# Memory leak in my GWT application

Tags: java, memory, gwt, memory-leaks

I have a web application created with GWT that has a memory leak.
honestly, I can't produce this memory leak but when we deploy the application in the client environment with many users we face a memory leak problem.

I received this file maybe it can help me, it has the objects in the memory when the memory leak produced.

```
2'777'369'064 (62.72%) [32] 8 class */planning/canvas/shared/serializable/ActionCycleSZ 0x68759f768
|- 2'777'365'536 (62.72%) [256] 35 org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader 0x688ce9df8
|  |- 2'775'589'272 (62.68%) [48] 1 java/util/HashMap 0x688ceabe0
|  |  |- 2'775'589'224 (62.68%) [32'784] 3'533 array of java/util/HashMap$Entry 0x689af74c0
|  |     |- 2'763'509'944 (62.41%) [24] 2 java/util/HashMap$Entry 0x68a0b1f98
|  |     |  |- 2'763'509'744 (62.41%) [40] 1 org/apache/catalina/loader/ResourceEntry 0x68a0b1fb0
|  |     |  |  |- 2'763'509'704 (62.41%) [32] 41 class
*/gwt/server/servlet/TaProjectsSessionManager 0x68653c8e8
|  |     |  |     |- 2'763'047'360 (62.4%) [32] 6 class */selfservice/SelfConfigurator 0x6875922a0
|  |     |  |     |  |- 2'763'047'328 (62.4%) [16] 2 */gwt/server/servlet/TaProjectsSessionManager$1 0x689aee328
|  |     |  |     |  |  |- 2'154'573'968 (48.66%) [160] 30 */impl/HRSessionImpl 0x689ee49f8
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |- 2'138'350'824 (48.29%) [32] 3 java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap 0x689ee4c70
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |- 2'138'350'760 (48.29%) [64] 3 org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap 0x689ee5218
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |- 2'134'913'368 (48.21%) [32] 2 org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractLinkedMap$LinkEntry 0x68a3573d0
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |- 3'437'328 (0.08%) [2'064] 121 array of org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractHashedMap$HashEntry 0x68a356bc8
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |- 16 (0%) [16] 1 org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractHashedMap$KeySet 0x69d443088
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |- 32 (0%) [16] 2 java/util/Collections$SynchronizedSet 0x69d443098
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |  |- 2'138'350'824 (48.29%) [32] 3 java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap 0x689ee4c70
|  |     |  |     |  |  |  |- 16'078'096 (0.36%) [104] 19 */impl/Dictionary 0x689ee4ad8
```

I conclude that the class ActionCycleSZ maybe produce the memory leak

this is ActionCycleSZ

```
public class ActionCycleSZ extends ActionDTO implements IsSerializable {
private CycleSZ bean;
public ActionCycleSZ() {
}
public ActionCycleSZ(Type actionType, CycleSZ bean ) {
super(actionType);
this.bean = bean;
}
public CycleSZ getBean(){
return bean;
}
public void setBean(CycleSZ bean){
this.bean = bean;
}
}
public class CycleSZ implements Serializable{
/**
*
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String cycleLabel;
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
String startDateDTO;
String endDateDTO;
Integer numlign;
String accumulatedHours;
List<SiteSZ> listOfSites = new LinkedList<SiteSZ>();
//getter and setter
}
public class SiteSZ implements Serializable {
/**
*
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int week;
String siteLabel;
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
String startHour;
String endHour;
String site;
String time;
String particularSlotTime;
Integer numlign;
DaySZ dayAttribute;
String accumulatedWeekHours;
Map<Util.WeekDays,DaySZ> mapAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<Util.WeekDays,DaySZ>();
boolean workedDay; //Flag for Exceptional Canevas Entry
boolean reposHebdo;
String contratId; //contratId for Exceptional Canevas Entry
```

ActionCycleSZ Contains the cycle and the action (create,delete,update)
this object will appear when the user create or  update or delete this object

```
eventBus.addHandler(CycleSaveEvent.TYPE, new CycleSaveHandler() {
        @Override       
        public void onCycleSaved(CycleSaveEvent event) {
final List<ActionCycleSZ> listCycleAction = new LinkedList<ActionCycleSZ>();
boolean newInsertion = getDetailsOfNewCycle(listCycleAction); //this methode can detect is there any new cycle and it will add actioncycleSZ 
        if (editedValuechange) {
            getDeletedCycle(listCycleAction);       
                    }                           
        if (!newInsertion) getDetailsOfOldCycle(listCycleAction);                                                                       getNotWorkedCycle(listOfNWSites,listCycleAction);
            updateCycle(listCycleAction);
```

when the method updateCycle() called the listCycleAction will have all the cycles so the method will call an RPC service to save the cycles

This is updateCycle

```
public void updateCycle(final List<ActionCycleSZ> listCycleAction) {
    //Call to service
     new  RpcCall2<String>() {
    @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            deletedListOfCycleSZ.clear();
                view.setChantierGridUpdated(false);
}
@Override
        public void onSuccess(final String message) {
            isNewCycle=false;

                SC.say(TAMessages.getMessage("ta.canvas.cycle.saved"), new BooleanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Boolean value) {
                   /* popup to make the user know that the cycle is saved */
}}}
                           @Override
                            protected void callService(AsyncCallback<AsyncCallback<String> callback) {
                                canvasServices.updateListActionCreatedCycle(listOfEmployees, listCycleAction, true, callback);
                            }
                  }.call();
```

I don't see anything that can make a memory leak so I install JProfiler to understand more my problem, I notice that the garbage collector for this object doesn't work whatever I call

> canvasServices.updateListActionCreatedCycle(listOfEmployees,listCycleAction,true, callback);

even if the method is empty, On the other hand, the object will disappear in the memory if I don't give the object in the RPC call

what is the cause of the memory leak? am I on the right path?
I want to indicate that I am using GWT 2.5. can it be that GWT makes the memory leak ?

Comment: Is the leak on the server, or on the client? The first paste you have seems to show server retaining info, which (at least for RPC) won't have anything to do with GWT. If the leak is on the client, you'll want to get heap diffs from inside the browser, not the JVM.

Comment: the leak is on the server

Comment: The act of calling `updateListActionCreatedCycle` asks the server to do work, it doesn't matter if the callback is empty or not. What matters is how those objects are deserialized (though you would have to be very ... creative to cause a leak there, check constructors for anything using static variables), or in your server `updateListActionCreatedCycle` method, or any of the protected RemoteServiceServlet overrides you might have added. Beyond that, without the ability to see your server code, it is hard to say much.